# Can DIAB compiler produce VXE without VxWorks?

Tags: vxworks

I have wrote a small application in C on VxWorks 6.9 evaluation. It uses sample code and makefile from windriver/target/usr/apps/samples. I would like to compile it for other platforms beside Intel.

I have downloaded DIAB compiler evaluation which comes with an impressive list of targets, however I have issues compiling my app, especially because it's missing make rules from target/usr/make etc.

What are my options to compile a RTP/VXE without VxWorks?

Or should I install DIAB evaluation on top of VxWorks Evaluation?

Thanks!

Comment: The paid version compiles with diab in the Wind River Work Bench (Eclipse) or command line, using VxWorks 6.9 
I don't see why you can't install diab as the compiler for the VxWorks 6.9 evaluation.